# cxf-codegen adding superfluous underscore in enum member name

Tags: cxf-codegen-plugin

I have the following generated enumeration type.  The issue I have is that for some reason (presumably capitalisation) that an underscore is inserted in the NCBonus value.

I would like to know how I can prevent that from happening when generating the enumeration.

```
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * <p>
 * <pre>
 * &lt;simpleType name="PromoType">
 *   &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string">
 *     &lt;enumeration value="MEM"/>
 *     &lt;enumeration value="COU"/>
 *     &lt;enumeration value="CHA"/>
 *     &lt;enumeration value="SAD"/>
 *     &lt;enumeration value="NCBonus"/>
 *   &lt;/restriction>
 * &lt;/simpleType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 */
@XmlType(name = "PromoType")
@XmlEnum
public enum PromoType {

    MEM("MEM"),
    COU("COU"),
    CHA("CHA"),
    SAD("SAD"),
    @XmlEnumValue("NCBonus")
    NC_BONUS("NCBonus");
```

I have tried using the global bindings option

```
   <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

which has undesired consequences on other objects but makes no different to the enum type.

In addition I have tried using

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/insurance_service_model.xsd" node="//xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='PromoType']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="NCBonus" value="NCBonus"/>
```

all to no avail.

Could someone please advise how I can achieve this goal please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was to move the jaxb bindings out of the jaxws bindings file.

**jaxb_bindings.xml**

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                jaxb:version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/insurance_service_model.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:simpleType[@name='PromoType']">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="PromoType">
                <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="NCBonus" value="NCBonus"/>
            </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

**wsdl_bindings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jaxws:bindings
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        wsdlLocation="../wsdl/insurance_service.wsdl"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">

    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

pom.xml

> ```
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
>             <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${cxf.codegen.version}</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>csg</id>
>                     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <wsdlOptions>
>                             <wsdlOption>
>                                 <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/v2_3/wsdl/insurance_service.wsdl</wsdl>
>                                 <extraargs>
>                                     <extraarg>-xjc-verbose</extraarg>
>                                     <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
>                                 </extraargs>
>                                 <bindingFiles>
>                                     <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/common_binding.xml</bindingFile>
>                                     <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/v2_3/bindings/wsdl_binding.xml</bindingFile>
>                                     <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/v2_3/bindings/jaxb_bindings.xml</bindingFile>
>                                 </bindingFiles>
>                             </wsdlOption>
>                         </wsdlOptions>
>                     </configuration>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>
>             </executions>
> ```